# Adding entry to NGINX virtual host file for FA Icons via CDN

Tags: wordpress, nginx, font-awesome, amazon-cloudfront, nginx-location

Trying to add the following code to my NGINX virtual host file to enable proper delivery of Font Awesome Icons via CDN (CORS Error)

[Ref:1](http://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/24-resolving-issues-with-cdn-and-fonts-icons) [Ref:2](https://fontawesomecdn.com/)

```
location ~ \.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css|js|gif|png|jpe?g|svg|svgz|ico|webp)$ {
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
}
```

I'm trying to add this to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf but doing so gives me a 500 error. Please advise on how to properly edit the virtual host file for my setup and edit the virtual host file. I'm using a wordpress based setup and /var/www/html is blank and I'm on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Where exactly are you adding that in your nginx.conf? Is it within a `server {}` block?

Comment: Upon rechecking, I didn't find it to be a part of my server block and hence it lead to a 500 error. Although, I've added the same within the server block {} to /home/admin/web/conf/nginx.conf, snginx.conf & etc/nginx/confd.myinternalip.conf without any respite